# CoordinatorLayout + TabView + AnimateView(From Top)

Tags: android, animation, scroll, android-tablayout, android-coordinatorlayout

`Yesterday` I am playing with `CoordinatorLayout` with `TabView`

**1) What is my target ?**

- `CoordinatorLayout`  with `TabView`
- When I `scroll up` at that time `One View` As show in **`.GIF`** `move down`.
- and `Stick` on the Top of the `TabView` (inside AppBar).

[image]

**2) Where I reached ?**

- `CoordinatorLayout`  with `TabView`  with pretty scrolling.
- TabView with Appbar Stop Scrolling At Top after Then Scroll RecyclerView.

[image]

3) **Where I stuck ?**

- When I `scroll Up` `One View` Scroll Down but TabView Stick `At Top` not like `1st gif`.

**4) Code snippet**

- Xml file

  ```
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
      <!--- ADD TAB_LAYOUT HERE -->


      <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
          android:id="@+id/main.collapsing"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
          app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
          app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll">

          <ImageView
              android:id="@+id/main.backdrop"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
              android:scaleType="centerCrop"
              android:src="@drawable/abc"
              app:layout_collapseMode="none" />


          <!-- ADD ANY THING THAT GETS SCROLLED ALL THE WAY UP WITH TOOLBAR -->
      </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


      <!-- our tablayout to display tabs  -->
      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
          android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
          android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
      android:id="@+id/pager"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
  ```
- Java file (move upper view down code)

  ```
  AppBarLayout ab = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_appbar);ab.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
      @Override
      public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {

          int ScrollStart = (ab.getHeight() - tabLayout.getHeight() - llTop.getHeight() - llTop.getHeight());
          int scrollStop = (ab.getHeight() - tabLayout.getHeight() - llTop.getHeight());
          if ((-verticalOffset) > ScrollStart && (-verticalOffset) < scrollStop) {
              llTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
              llTop.setTranslationY(((-verticalOffset) - ScrollStart) - llTop.getHeight());
              Log.e("point", "" + ((-verticalOffset) - ScrollStart));

          } else if ((-verticalOffset) >= scrollStop) {
              llTop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          } else {
              llTop.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          }


      }
  });
  ```

Comment: add tab layout inside collapsing toolbar layout

Comment: then it will hide when i scroll

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22648424/how-can-i-make-a-single-header-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-when-scrolling-a-l  this might solve it

Comment: Due to differnet scroll behaviour   sticky header  not work i thing because of TabView scroll up that time  layout scroll down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's tricky little bit..

just try to  **setMinimumHeight** of your **CollapsingToolbarLayout** like this way and do let me know.

```
CollapsingToolbarLayout layoutCollapsing = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.layoutCollapsing);
layoutCollapsing.setMinimumHeight(120);
```

here calculate your minimum height as per your need and set it in place  of **setMinimumHeight(120)** value.

Comment: Thank you so much .. after 2 days i can solve it.  with add just one line  android:minHeight="".  I accept your ans :)

Comment: your wc ..:)  any time and every time .