# SearchView overlaps with statusbar?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity with ConstraintLayout as the root view of my layout. Inside i have added custom toolbar. Inside toolbar I have added 2 linear layout vertically.
The first linear layout have SearchView inside that. When i try to run appliaction my Searchview overlaps with StatusBar of android. I have added android:fitsSystemWindows="true" to my root layout. But no use...

Here is my Layout file

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/parent_lay"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/searchLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/ncc_blue"
        android:visibility="gone">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/searchTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:background="#1AFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/tvSearchKey"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/robotomedium"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/ncc_white"
                android:textColorHint="#66FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                app:closeIcon="@drawable/ic_close_white_24dp"
                app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                app:queryHint="000-000-000-000"
                app:searchIcon="@drawable/ic_search_24dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/searchTop"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:background="#1AFFFFFF"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_calendar_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="19dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/robotomedium"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="Any Date"
                android:textColor="@color/ncc_white"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

here is my V-21/styles.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

here is my issue

[image]

I tried this link, but no use
[Toolbar overlapping below status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29738510/toolbar-overlapping-below-status-bar)

Comment: android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" attribute gives fixed size to your toolbar(Probably 60-70dp). set hard-code size like 120dp and check weather your toolbar is displaying fully or not!

Comment: It is showing fully when I give static height. But I want it to have minHeight to its default height. Some other cases I used it

Comment: you need to calculate `?attr/actionBarSize (value)` and providing `2 * (that value) + (padding/margin of ur view if you want in toolbar)`. Without static height it is not possible

Comment: Can we achieve this without minHeight property using wrap_content as a layoutHeight

Comment: Why this is happening. Am not setting the layout height property to ?attr/actionBarSize. Am only setting this value to minHeight property. Why it is affecting the layout_height property that has weap_content value.

Comment: you are still unclear to me bro! anyway refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43715281/1848157

Comment: I adjust value at runtime. Now it is working

Comment: great! kindly close your question with self given answer.so other developers can take reference this.